# What is the difference between the Box API and OneCloud APIs and is the iPhone sdk OneCloud only?

Tags: android, ios, box-api

I am a bit confused as to what the REST API and OneCloud API actually are and how they relate to one another.

Also on android there is a an SDK for the REST API and OneCloud is there the same for IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally the REST API runs on Box's servers, and the OneCloud API runs on the iOS/Android devices themselves.

What else may have you confused is that there are actually 2 separate iOS SDKs.  One for dealing with REST API calls, and another for calling OneCloud API calls.   Some app developers want both, so they get both SDKs.  Other apps only need one or the other.   We split them up to keep the packaging lighter.

Comment: So there is no difference on the server end whichever API is used, if I upload a file using either API the result is the same in the end? Somehow I got it into my head that the Onecloud was for the app to use the users Box account to store its own data and the rest api for traditional file storage

Comment: Also do you have a link for the IOS version of the REST API SDK? I can only find the OneCloud version

Comment: Send us your github account at api@box.com and we will get you access

Answer (score 0):

The REST API calls our web service APIs (i.e. [those listed here](http://developers.box.com/docs))

The OneCloud SDK provides a framework for sending data directly to and from  the Box for Android/iOS apps.

Comment: Is there an IOS REST SDK I can only see the OneCloud one?